# Redirect subdomain to domain and keep everything after the URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need redirect my subdomain

> http://sub.domain.com

to

> http://domainB.com/news

I'm tested various posibilities in htaccess without any result.

This code works fine, but rediret from domain, not from subdomain...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://subdomain.domainB.com/$1 [P]
```

This code redirect domain.com to

> https://subdomain.domainB.com

and preserve domain.com in address bar and works correctly. I want subdomain to subdomainB.

I need help, please.

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to match against subdomain in RewriteCond.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://subdomain.domainB.com/$1 [P]
```

Comment: Put this code in Document root? Or in the subdomain folder?

Comment: The code is ok and there is nothing in the code that can cause 500 error. Please check your  error log for more info about the error

Comment: where I put the code htaccess? In the / folder or in subdomain folder? Thanks

Comment: Then, You have to put this in  /subdomain/.htaccess

Comment: Ok, I'm going to testing

Comment: I fixed the 500 error by adding `SSLProxyEngine On`, clearified it in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by [starkeen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3160747/starkeen), you should add **`SSLProxyEngine On`** when using `SSLEngine on` to your Apache settings, or this will throw an internal server error (500):

```
SSLEngine on
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/XXXXX_webserver_ssl.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/XXXXX_webserver_ssl.key

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domainA\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://subdomain.domainB.com/$1 [P,L]
```